# finding a way to replace images to proper url's

Tags: replace, coldfusion

i am getting contents from a website: The images are coming as: /images/abc.gif, so what it is doing is it is attaching my website url to it and giving me network error: here is an example of this

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://devl.example.com/segment/Images/HeadCont.gif"
HeadCont.gif
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://devl.example.com/segment/images/NewDetails.gif"
NewDetails.gif
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://devl.example.com/segment/Images/HeadSurr.gif"
```

i am using this code for replace of images

```
<cfset lnk = replace(lnk,'"/images/sym_s_up.gif"','"http://thewebsite.com/images/sym_s_up.gif"','ALL')>
```

but the above is doing for the image i specify, how can i write some kind of single code where it searches all the /images and replace them with the url irrespective of the image name i have to specify

Comment: Sounds like you are screen scraping. While there are legitimate reasons for doing so, it still seems....not right. You could use jSoup - http://jsoup.org/ -  to manipulate the `src` on the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the actual image name and search for a consistent string

```
<cfset lnk = replace(lnk,'/images/','http://thewebsite.com/images/','ALL')>
```

You could also take the approach of replacing something like `<img src="/images` and replacing that with your full url.